# Query SubReport based on checkboxes on Main Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, filter, vba, subforms

I have the following Main Form "Edit Services" with a Sub Form "Edit Services SubForm":

[image]

I want to filter the Sub Form based on the check box at the top of the Main Form that correlates to fields in the Sub Form that are on a Yes/No criteria.

I.E. If the In-Shop box is checked then it should filter anything that has In-Shop as Yes in the Sub Form.  If it is unchecked it should clear the filter.

**ANSWER**

```
Private Sub chbxInShop_Click()
    If Me.chbxInShop.Value Then
        Me.[Edit Services SubForm].Form.Filter = "[SrvInShop] = True"
        Me.[Edit Services SubForm].Form.FilterOn = True
        Me.[Edit Services SubForm].Form.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But what does happen instead?  Does Access complain when it encounters this? ... `.Form.Filter = "In-Shop = 'Yes'"`  If so, perhaps you need ... `.Form.Filter = "[In-Shop] = True"`

Comment: I get the following error, no matter if it's In-Shop = Yes or [In-Shop] = True...

"Run-time error '2465':
Microsoft Access can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression."

Comment: That error message suggests the subform's record source does not include a field named `In-Shop`.  Please double-check.

Comment: Note if you assigned a `Caption` for the field name in table design, the column header, `In-Shop`, is the field's `Caption` rather than it's name.  You must use the field name in the `Filter` expression.

Comment: Is it based off the table or the subform field names?  Still not having much luck with it.

Comment: You need to use the name of the field from the subform's record source, which is either a table or a query.  What is the record source?

Comment: I got it... thanks. I mislabeled the SubForm, the correct code I needed was:

Private Sub chbxInShop_Click()
    If Me.chbxInShop.Value Then
        Me.[Edit Services SubForm].Form.Filter = "[SrvInShop] = True"
        Me.[Edit Services SubForm].Form.FilterOn = True
        Me.[Edit Services SubForm].Form.Requery
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Aha!  Guard against similar problems in the future by including `Option Explicit` in the Declarations sections of all your code modules.  And then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  That effort will alert you to anything in the code, such as an incorrect object name, which Access doesn't recognize.  Never code VBA without `Option Explicit`!

Comment: How can I clear the filter?  I tried Me.[Edit Services SubForm].Form.Filter = ""
        Me.[Edit Services SubForm].Form.FilterOn = False

Comment: I'm unsure.  Did you first add `Option Explicit` and then run Debug->Compile?

Comment: Yes... everything is good. Thanks : What I am wanting is when I un-check the box it removes the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample database, it seems the code had the True and False conditions reversed.  For example, the following line means *"If chbxInShop is False (un-checked) then do the following"*, which is to apply the subform filter.  But you really want to apply the filter when the check box is checked ... meaning its `.Value` is True (-1).

```vb
If Me.chbxInShop.Value = 0 Then
```

I tested the following code for the check box's After Update event with your form, and it does what I think you're asking for.

```vb
Private Sub chbxInShop_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strFilter As String

    strFilter = vbNullString ' make it explicit
    If Me.chbxInShop.Value = True Then
        strFilter = "[SrvInShop] = True"
    End If
    With Me.[Edit Services SubForm].Form
        .Filter = strFilter
        .FilterOn = Me.chbxInShop.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

If you later decide you want the subform filter based on the values of all 4 of the form's check boxes, you'll need to examine each of them and create an  appropriate `Filter` string, which could wind up as something like ...

```vb
strFilter = "[SrvInShop] = True AND [SrvSmallBusiness] = True"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in the original post. I had mislabeled the SubForm...